# Plotly or Bokeh Offline - Update chart based on search box

Tags: python, plotly, bokeh, plotly-python, pandas-bokeh

Just theoretical question because i couldn't find anything on internet. I would like to create plotly or bokeh (wherever is possible) **offline interactive chart where Search Box will be available and chart will be updated by typing proper text**, something similar to drop down menu but my database contains more than 500 cars and its extremely difficult to find proper one with drop down.

I heard that such functionality is easily achieved via bokeh/plotly server running, however i cannot do that - only thing i can do is share HTML with my colleagues.

Additionaly someone mentioned about editing plotly html with javascript so i can get what i want but without any example its too difficult.

Comment: Offline interactive charts can be made. User input can be taken via Bokeh. More detailed explaination here:https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/widgets.html But would be helpful if you can elaborate a little more

Comment: I saw this but im very unexperienced with bokeh and i dont know how to start...